# Cannot Create Index in PL SQL

Tags: plsql

I am just a beginner to PL SQL and trying to explore queries with PL SQL on Oracle 11g express edition. I am unable to create an Index using PL SQL procedure call.  I am getting an error Error report: ORA-06550

```
BEGIN
CREATE INDEX employee_empid_index ON employee(empid);
END;
```

What modifications should I make in my Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using DDL queries in PL/SQL. PL/SQL should be used for run time things like fetching data from one table to another table(e.g. schedule a job that copies data from one table to another table on hourly basis for back up). Table creation, index creation should be done with normal sql beforehand.

In short PL/SQL is not intended to do the jobs of DDL. Some DDL statements inside PL SQL are however allowed. [This article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_using_ddl_create_index_table_plsql.htm) explains the same very well

Answer (score 2):

DDL statements (such as `CREATE TABLE` .. or `CREATE INDEX`) are not allows in `PL/SQL` context; (PL/SQL context is between `BEGIN` and `END`).
However you can execute them using Dynamic SQL syntax within `PL/SQL` block.

Example

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX employee_empid_index ON employee(empid);'
END;
```

Or just execute them within `SQL` context.

```
CREATE INDEX employee_empid_index ON employee(empid);
```

Comment: The statement to be executed within the quotes shouldn't have a semi-colon So it should be EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE INDEX employee_empid_index ON employee(empid)';

Answer (score 0):

in this case you must not use the "begin" and "end" terms , Remove those terms and try it again.